# Has a horse ever crossed the finish line first without a jockey?

Tags: horse-racing

At the 2019 Preakness Stakes, jockey John Velazquez fell off his horse Bodexpress at the start of the race, but Bodexpress continued to finish the race.  Officially Bodexpress received a "DNF" (Did Not Finish) because the rule is that a horse cannot finish without a jockey.

But has there ever been a race in which a horse without a jockey was the first to cross the finish line?

Answer (score 1):

[Luigi Bruschelli has won 13 palios since 1996, one of which his horse finished first without him](https://www.gq-magazine.co.uk/article/palio-horse-race-siena-film).